# select and deselect images on a web page with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I have list of images on the web page. I want to click on image to select it and want to display selected image on the same page. By clicking on selected image, i want to deselect it.
I have displayed the sketch below. Can someone please help me with jquery code, how to do it.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: What have you come up with yourself, so far?

Comment: I only can display images from database, but i dont have knowledge of jquery or javascript so im looking for any help with the jquery to select the images.

Comment: To Jochem's point, you're not so much looking for help with the jquery as much as you're looking for the jquery.  We're all happy to help, but we're not just going to write the code for you and hand it over.  If you "don't have knowledge of jquery", I'd suggest you start at jquery.com and do some reading.  Try some examples.  Then tackle the question above.  When you encounter specific obstacles, ask about those.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I understand and I'll be more careful while asking again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BshUj/1/) is something to start with.

```
 $('#selectList img')
    .each(function(i, el){
        $(this).addClass('img' + i); // identtify imgs by index (class="imgN")
    })
    .click(function(){
        var $img = $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        if($img.hasClass('clicked'))
            output.append($img.clone().removeClass('clicked'));
        else
            output.find('.' + $img[0].className).remove();
    });
```